# Wiring a USB device to act as a Serial port

Tags: opto-isolator, usb-device, serial-bus

I'm trying to make a cable that will go from a laptop usb port through an opto-isolator to a 4-pin connector on a circuit board, and I'm trying to communicate via Asynchronous IN/OUT. I have some python code to open the port and read/write. The problem I'm running into on windows (and linux) is that I get an error saying "Device descriptor request failed."

So it's not recognizing the device. I don't know if there's an override I need to do or something I need to wire differently. What should I be doing differently to achieve this?
[image: Wiring Schematic]
Thank you!

Comment: Please post a schematic of your circuit and post your formatted code using the `{}` code button. It sounds as though you think you can just treat USB in the same way as an RS232 serial port. Is this the case?

Comment: Serial and USB are very different, you need another chip to go between them.

Comment: If you search on Ebay for `cisco console cable usb` you will find many cheap, blue, cables with built-in FTDI usb-serial convertors.  These are excellent for connecting to simple microcontroller systems.  Then you'll have signals you can use with opto-isolators.

Comment: USB and UART are not the same thing. It's like trying to plug a piece of bread into a VCR. You need a USB-UART bridge. The drivers installed on the PC will make the USB side look like a terminal which you can then use with your PC-side software.

Comment: @DKNguyen: You need to update your comparisons. Nobody younger than 20 knows what a VCR is.

Comment: @Janka It's like sticking a CD into an minidisc player? Still too dated? It's like sticking a Blu-Ray disc into an MP3 player?

Comment: @Janka 20 years from now, Bread™ will be the number one content delivered format and the entire world has gone gluten-free™.

Comment: @winny It will have been the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: I would say more like sticking a DVD into a CD player.  I can buy both of them  at Walmart right now so thats not an excuse...  And while most CD's will workjust fine in a DVD player, the reversal is not true.